# Change Windows 7 password from Linux?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, passwords

I forgot the administrator password for a Windows 7 VM. I booted from an Ubuntu ISO image, and mounted the Windows 7 hard drive, so I can hack around, but I can't use the 'net users' Windows command. Why doesn't this work? What else can I try?

Answer (score 2):

Use [chntpw](http://freshmeat.net/projects/chntpw/)